# BeautifulSoup grab only once within a given tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to grab a parent tag if it contains within it a marker, let's say MARKER. So for example, I have:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c>
  MARKER
  </c>
 </b>
 <b>
  <c>
  MARKER
  MARKER
  </c>
 </b>
 <b>
  <c>
  stuff
  </c>
 </b>
</a>
```

I would like to grab:

```
 <b>
  <c>
  MARKER
  </c>
 </b>

 <b>
  <c>
  MARKER
  MARKER
  </c>
 </b>
```

My current code is:

```
for stuff in soup.find_all(text=re.compile("MARKER")):
        post = stuff.find_parent("b")
```

This works, sort of, however, it gives me:

```
 <b>
  <c>
  MARKER
  </c>
 </b>

 <b>
  <c>
  MARKER
  MARKER
  </c>
 </b>

 <b>
  <c>
  MARKER
  MARKER
  </c>
 </b>
```

The reason that this is happening is obvious, it's printing the entire containing tag once for every MARKER it finds, so the tag containing two MARKERs gets printed twice. However, I'm not sure how to how to tell BeautifulSoup to not search within given tag after it's done (I suspect that, specifically, cannot be done?) or otherwise prevent this, other than perhaps indexing everything to a dictionary and rejecting duplicates?

EDIT:
This is the specific case I'm working on that's giving me trouble, since for some reason, the above doesn't actually produce the error despite being a stripped version. (The particular forum thread I'm fetching a a play-by-post, if anyone's curious.)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

url = 'http://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/asukaquest-3-starfish-eater.258271/page-179'
soup = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
sbsoup = BeautifulSoup(soup)

for stuff in sbsoup.find_all(text=re.compile("\[[Xx]\]")):
        post = stuff.find_parent("li")
        print(post.find("a", class_="username").string)
        print(post.find("blockquote", class_="messageText ugc baseHtml").get_text())
```

Comment: Are you using version 3 of BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Interesting, because when I run it, it works fine for me

Comment: Uh? Maybe I misrepresented myself? It runs fine for me too, but it gives me multiple iterations if the tag contains more than one marker.

Comment: Yes, but mine only prints MARKER MARKER once

Comment: Hmm. I'll take a look at my code when I get back to my computer and see if I copied it wrongly, I guess?

Comment: Ok. The stripped code, using the generic example I posted _does_ in fact work properly, but when I run it in conjunction with the html I fetch from a website, it gives me the doubled entries. Is it frowned upon to give out my exact work example here?

Comment: Go ahead :). That's probably the only way this will get answered

Comment: Edited in the specific case. Don't mind the website.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this with bs3, it might work with bs4 but the concepts are the same. Basically, the li tags have the user name in them under the "data-author" attribute, so you don't need to find a lower tag and then hunt for the parent li.

It seems that you are only interested in blockquote tags containing the "marker", so why not specify that ?

Lambda functions are generally the most versatile way of querying Beautiful soup.

```
import os
import sys

# Import System libraries
import re
import urllib2

# Import Custom libraries
#from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# The url variable to be searched
url = 'http://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/asukaquest-3-starfish-eater.258271/page-179'
# Create a request object
request = urllib2.Request(url)

# Attempt to open the request and read the response
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    the_page = response.read()
except Exception:
    the_page = ""
    # If the response exists, create a BeautifulSoup from it
if(the_page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page)

    # Define the search location for the desired tags
    li_location = lambda x: x.name == u"li" and set([("class", "message   ")]) <= set(x.attrs)
    x_location = lambda x: x.name == u"blockquote" and bool(re.search("\[[Xx]\]", x.text))

    # Iterate through all the found lis
    for li in soup.findAll(li_location):
        # Print the author name
        print dict(li.attrs)["data-author"]
        # Iterate through all the found blockquotes containing the marker
        for xs in li.findAll(x_location):
            # Print the text of the found blockquote
            print xs.text
        print ""
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking the time. Secondly, I'm not, in fact, only interested in the segment under the blockquote, and will be extracting more information from under the li tag later, when I clear up this particular problem. Thirdly, I'm not that advanced in Python yet, could you explain what's going on, particularly with the lambda function? (I know what a lambda function is, but I'm having trouble understanding these ones.) Lastly, I'd actually quite like to know what's wrong with my current implementation, to further my understanding. Again, thanks.

Comment: If you're interested in all tags containing the "marker" then simply remove the x.name == u"blockquote" from the x_location lambda function. In BeautifulSoup, if a function (in this case, lambdas) are passed to the find methods (find, findAll, etc.) they will be used for the test. Specifically, the x argument of the lambda functions will be a BeautifulSoup tag. BeautifulSoup tags have name, attrs and text members, which are accessed in those lambda functions. With HTML parsing, you want your search methodology to match-up with the structure of the webpage. I've added comments to the code.

Comment: I see. So `soup.findAll(li_location)` is equivalent to `soup.findAll("li",class_="message")`? What does the `<=x.attrs` do? (To my reading it means less than or equal to the .attrs of the tag being tested...?) And again, any idea what's wrong with my implementation?

Comment: I believe they are equivalent but lambdas are more extensible should you wish to test for something more complicated. Python has a data structure called set: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29. The set(A) <= set(B) is testing whether A is a total subset of B; so if the test became set([("class", "message"), ("id", "someid")]) <= set(x.attrs) it would require the tag's id attribute to be "someid". By searching in a hierarchical fashion (as in, parent first), you can prevent successive matches.

Comment: Ah. I see, thank you! I'll tinker around with it and see if I can get it to run, then. (I'm on Python 3.3, and the code doesn't run. The immediate problem is, of course, the print, which I have changed to print(), but beyond that, it simply gives me no output when run.)

Comment: bs4 code you posted had find_all instead of findAll. Maybe change all the findAll to find_all?

Comment: No, I changed that too. Still giving me no output.