# Concatenating strings in place in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wish to extend a string value in a dictionary. Obviously, I can do it by:

```
dictionary = dict()
listofstrings = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
for stuff in listofstrings:
    if "key" in dictionary:
        dictionary["key"] = dictionary["key"] + stuff
    else:
        dictionary["key"] = stuff
```

However, is there a better way to do this? Something like setdefault()? (That only works if there's a function call after the setdefault, eg. append or update, as I understand it.)

Comment: `{'key':''.join(listofstrings)}` ?

Comment: Nah, that's just an example. I won't actually be using a list of strings, rather, strings parsed from a document.

Comment: But they would still be strings, right?

Comment: @Firnagzen: Explain your exact situation. Changing crucial details won't really help.

Comment: I'm using BeautifulSoup to search through a HTML document, and then building a dictionary of text indexed to other text in the document. The direct code for this section would be something like `for stuff in soup.find_all("blah"):` which is then added to dictionary["key"]. The key is varied by another section of the program. I haven't entirely nailed down the code for this, which is why I didn't give that initially.

Comment: @Firnagzen Show us the BS code please :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439355/ I still haven't worked out this section fully yet, is the problem. I intend to index the post by the username instead of printing as in the link. Was attempting to take a break by working on another portion instead, but little did I know... And my apologies for not giving this section earlier, but I didn't think it was that relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for stuff in listofstrings:
    dictionary["key"] = dictionary.get("key",defaultvalueforkey) + stuff
```

in your case, defaultvalueforkey should be "".

Comment: Hm. So there isn't a way to do it in place, like `dictionary.setdefault("key",[]).append(integer)` for a dictionary of lists?

Comment: You can create your own `class dictsubclass(dict):def appendtokey(self,key,appendage): self[key] = self.get(key,"") + appendage` and use that instead of the original dict; it will have the desired functionality.